# Taking output of /dev/tty into a variable

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I created a two backup scripts - one for files (filebackup.sh) and another for database (dbbackup.sh). `filebackup.sh` calls `dbbackup.sh` and stores the output in a variable. The output returned by `dbbackup.sh` is the tar filename in which the script has stored all the backed up databases.

The script `dbbackup.sh` contains the following at the end:

```
echo $TARFILE > /dev/tty
```

The script `filebackup.sh` calls dbbackup.sh like this:

```
DBBACKUP="`/scripts/dbbackup.sh &>/dev/null`"
```

This dumps all extra output from the script to /dev/null and ensures only the filename is returned.

Everything works except when I call filebackup.sh, the filename is printed to screen. The variable `$DBBACKUP` remains empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

In short: just remove the `>/dev/tty` part from `dbbackup.sh`; use just:

```
echo $TARFILE
```

This will print $TARFILE to the standard output, i.e., to the screen if you're running `dbbackup.sh` in a terminal, or to the a file/pipe if redirection is in place (as happens with the shell backquote/`$(...)` expansion).

There is also another reason why the thing won't work, even if you correct the issue above: your `dbbackup.sh` script prints the tar file name to standard output, but in the line

```
DBBACKUP="`dbbackup.sh >&/dev/null`"
```

you are discarding any output coming from `dbbackup.sh` (by redirecting it to `/dev/null`).  If you only wanted to discard errors, then use the `2>/dev/null` redirection.

Longer story: the line

```
echo $TARFILE > /dev/tty
```

redirects the output of the `echo` command to `/dev/tty` (the terminal to which the current process is attached) instead of printing to the standard output stream shared by other commands in the `dbbackup.sh` script. Therefore, when you further redirect the output of `dbbackup.sh` in `dbbackup.sh >&/dev/null`, this second redirection does not affect the `echo` command.

You might want to read a bit more on [shell redirection](http://www.injunea.demon.co.uk/pages/page208.htm) and [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).